# How do i make the "View Listing" button always be at the bottom of the listing

Tags: html, css

[What the Listings look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxOG6.png)

I would like the blue "View Listing" button to go to the bottom of the outline box regardless of the size of the title. Right now its inconsistent as some are in the middle some are at the bottom.

I will add a maximum number of characters the title can be later on as the title getting longer is making all the listings taller aswell.

This is my first attempt at doing something with html and css on my own and a lot might be wrong with it.

My HTML structure:

```
<div className="listings-container">
            <h2 className="listings-title">Latest Listings</h2>

            <div className='listings'>

                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-image">
                        <img src={ebay1} alt="..." />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <h3>DARK GREEN FOREST NIKE AIR FORCE 1 LIMITED</h3>
                        <p>$15</p>
                        <button className="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-image">
                        <img src={ebay2} alt="..." />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <h3>NIKE AIR FORCE 1 UTILITY (GS) BLACK-GUM BROWN SZ 6Y-WOMENS [AJ6601-003]</h3>
                        <p>$100</p>
                        <button className="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-image">
                        <img src={ebay3} alt="..." />
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <h3>nike air force 1 mid SF AF1 youth shoes size 6.5 mushroom</h3>
                        <p>$30</p>
                        <button className="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.listings {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    width: min-content;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 2px, rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.65) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) 0px 1px 0px inset;
    transition: .4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
}

.card .card-image {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
}

.card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
}

.card .card-content h3 {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.card .card-content p {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 8px 0 22px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.card-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5em;
    background: var(--complimentary);
    border: none;
    border-radius: .25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .25em;
    -moz-border-radius: .25em;
    -ms-border-radius: .25em;
    -o-border-radius: .25em;
}

.card-button:hover {
    background-color: var(--lightBlue);
}
```

Comment: When you're happy with my answer please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex-layout for your cards and card-content. Adding flex-grow: 1 to to card-content makes it fill the available height.
justify-content: space-between adds maximum space between all including elements.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.listings {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card {
    width: min-content;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 2px, rgba(6, 24, 44, 0.65) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08) 0px 1px 0px inset;
    transition: .4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
}

.card .card-image {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
}

.card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 250px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
}

.card .card-content h3 {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.card .card-content{
  flex-grow:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card .card-content p {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 8px 0 22px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.card-button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5em;
    background: grey;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .25em;
    -moz-border-radius: .25em;
    -ms-border-radius: .25em;
    -o-border-radius: .25em;
}

.card-button:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="listings-container">
  <h2 class="listings-title">Latest Listings</h2>

  <div class='listings'>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3>DARK GREEN FOREST NIKE AIR FORCE 1 LIMITED</h3>
        <p>$15</p>
        <button class="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3>nike air force 1 mid SF AF1 youth shoes size 6.5 mushroom</h3>
        <p>$30</p>
        <button class="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="..." />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3>nike air force 1 mid SF AF1 youth shoes size 6.5 mushroom nike air force 1 mid SF AF1 youth shoes size 6.5 mushroom nike air force 1 mid SF AF1 youth shoes size 6.5 mushroom</h3>
        <p>$30</p>
        <button class="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the price right under your heading just add a wrapper:

```
 <div class="card-content">
    <div>
      <h3>my title</h3>
      <p>$30</p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn card-button">View Listing</button>
  </div>
```